# How to set a header to a value from a properties file in Apache Camel

Tags: java, apache-camel

Is it possible to set a message header to a value read from a properties file, using the camel *Properties Component*? I can set such properties to URI options, but I'm unable to set them as a header values.

I need something like this:

```
<camel:setHeader headerName="actionId">
    <camel:constant>{{onus.transPosting.RtSFailed}}</camel:constant>
</camel:setHeader>
```

where `onus.transPosting.RtSFailed` is a property key set on a file imported using camel Properties Component.

Note: I'm using Apache Camel 2.10.1

**UPDATE**

Using the `<propertyPlaceholder>` as suggested by [this discussion](http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/using-values-from-a-properties-file-in-setHeader-method-td5154287.html) did not work and it causes an exception:

`Caused by: org.apache.camel.language.simple.types.SimpleParserException: Unknown function: onus.transPosting.RtSFailed`

Comment: `<simple>${onus.transPosting.RtsFailed}</simple>` does not work? (As good as no experience with Apache Camel)

Comment: See this discussion: http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/using-values-from-a-properties-file-in-setHeader-method-td5154287.html

Comment: thanks Konstantin, plz check my update on the post

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you can, use the simple language which has a properties function: http://camel.apache.org/simple

```
<camel:setHeader headerName="actionId">
    <camel:simple>${properties:onus.transPosting.RtSFailed}</camel:simple>
</camel:setHeader>
```

Though I think we have fixed in latest Camel releases that < camel:constant > will resolve property placeholders as well.

Comment: My bad, I should've mentioned what release I'm using, I updated the question accordingly. Anyway, the simple properties function worked for me. Thank you very much :)